# Stick two faces to each other with different rotation

Tags: faces

I am trying to stick two faces to each other. These two faces are of the same size, but do not have the same rotation.
I tried to do it manually and I of course experimented with the magnet tool, but it did not work well till now. Is there a possibility to mark two faces like "that they belong together" and stick perfectly to each other like magnets?

Thank you, Huxi

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56882/how-do-you-rotate-an-object-so-that-a-particular-face-is-parallel-to-the-ground/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80641/rotate-an-ico-sphere-with-20-sidesicosahedron-to-align-with-the-level-grid

Comment: @Duarte and others. This question specifically illustrates joined geometry of which only 2 faces are to be manipulated. All other question refer to object level transformations. I don't think it's the same. [This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107803/connecting-the-endpoints-of-2-tubes-while-only-moving-one?noredirect=1&lq=1) is much more similiar. (Edit mode, joined, cylinder shape.)